# Looking for formula to extract specific values from a row containing numbers and blanks

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with rows of data, with many columns. I am looking for help on a formula that will extract the sum of the smallest 3 numbers in a row based on the last 5 values entered. Note that not all the rows will have values for each column, so the first value found on each row will may be found in a different column.

To determine the sum of the smallest 3 I am using the formula `=SUM(SMALL(B3:R3,{1,2,3}))`,   Unfortunately, that formula is looking at the entire range. Again, I am looking for help that with a formula that will select only the last 5 values posted.

Here is simple example.  The results for each line show the totals that should be determined.  Again, it needs to look for the sum of the smallest 3 based on the last 5 posted (in the example below the range would be col. 1 thru 10, with col 10 having the latest postings).

Ex.
1.....2.....3......4......5.....6.....7.....8......9.....10......  Result
31.........44....51....36..........44...34....36....38.......106 (34+36+34)
35..31...44...40.....38...52..........42....37...............115 (37+38+40)

Hope this is understandable. I am looking for a formula solution vs a VBA macro solution because of my users. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Can you define "the _latest_ 10 values" better? Do you mean "the 10 rightmost cells in the row that have values in them", "the last 10 values in the column that have values", "the last numbers that the user entered, regardless of location", ...? You mention "weeks" - how are they arranged? Is data contiguous? So much that is still unclear. You could create a sample using just text and space, and code formatting (with the `{}` button as you edit). It's how people did pictures before they could do pictures...

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated my post with an example that I hope will help clarify what I am hoping to find a solution to.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would it be OK to have some hidden fields in another part of the sheet - with the blanks cells it may be hard to come up with a single expression that does it all...

Answer (score 0):

Now that you clarified the question, I have an answer for you. This is fairly ugly but it gets the job done. You might want to hide the columns with the intermediate results - or you could get adventurous and "nest" the expressions. This makes it really hard to understand / debug though. If there's a smarter way to do this I am always open to learning.

Assuming you have the data in columns `A` through `J`, starting in row 2, put the following in cell `L2:P2`:

```
=MATCH(9999, A2:J2,1)
=MATCH(9999,OFFSET($A2,0,0, 1, L2-1))    ... copy this by dragging right to the next 2 columns
=MATCH(9999,OFFSET($A2,0,0, 1, M2-1))
=MATCH(9999,OFFSET($A2,0,0, 1, N2-1))
=MATCH(9999,OFFSET($A2,0,0, 1, O2-1))
```

The first line finds the last cell with data in it; the next ones find the last cell "not including the last cell", and so they work backwards. The result is a number corresponding to the columns with data. For your example, this gives

```
10  9  8  7  5
 9  8  6  5  4
```

Now we want to find the sum of the smallest 3 of these: put the following equation in cell `Q2`:

```
=SUM(SMALL(INDIRECT("RC["&P2-17&"]:RC["&L2-17&"]",FALSE),{1,2,3}))
```

Working from the inside out:

```
RC["&P2-17"]        results in RC[-12], which is "the cell 12 to the left of this one".
                    That is the first of the "last five cells with data", cell E2
RC["&L2-17"]        results in RC[-7], the last cell with data in this row
FALSE               use "RC" rather than "A1" indexing
INDIRECT            turn string into an address (in this case a range)
SMALL               find the 3 smallest values in this range
SUM                 and add them together.
```

This formula did indeed give me `106, 115` for the example you provided.

I would hide columns L through P so you only see the result (and not the intermediate stuff).

Comment: Hi Floris, I don't think this works correctly for what I am trying to do. I do not think it is recognizing blank cells.  I have updated my post with a better example.  Sorry for the confusion at first!

Comment: Fair point - your question wasn't quite clear initially. Now that it's better I have given an updated answer... this should work now.